# Most effective way to aggregate clob value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, aggregate-functions, clob

I have a table like:

```
SOME_ID FIRST_CLOB   ANOTHER_CLOB
0       1.5|3.6|0.3  5.5|9.6
1       0.2          4.0|7.2
2       3.1|0.7|1.2  9.2|8.8|6.3
```

Length of clob is not defined. It could (and in reality will be) much longer than in example.

I need to get something like that:

```
SOME_ID FIRST_CLOB_MEAN ANOTHER_CLOB_MEAN
0       1.8             7.55
1       0.2             5.6
2       1.66            8.1
```

It could be not only a mean, but a count for example. Now we counting it when processing data in pandas but **it takes very long time** to load a table with clob values.

I see only one way: create a trigger on input which would:

1.Split every CLOB field like that:

```
CLOB
1.5
3.6
0.3
```

2.Find mean value from it

I'm not sure is that best way to do it and will it work if I'm importing table from csv. Will be grateful for advices

P.S. I have another solution: just split CLOB without aggregation like that:

```
NEW_ID SOME_ID FIRST_CLOB   ANOTHER_CLOB
0      0       1.5          5.5
1      0       3.6          9.6
2      0       0.3          NULL
3      1       0.2          4.0
4      1       NULL         7.2
5      2       3.1          9.2
6      2       0.7          8.8
7      2       1.2          6.3
```

It will load to pandas faster but the table will be increased enormously(one CLOB can contain 10,25,50,100 items) and its also undesirable

Comment: The better solution is to fix this horrible data model and normalize your CLOB values into rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
WITH bounds ( some_id, first_clob, start1, end1, another_clob, start2, end2 ) AS (
  SELECT some_id,
         first_clob,
         1,
         INSTR( first_clob, '|', 1 ),
         another_clob,
         1,
         INSTR( another_clob, '|', 1 )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT some_id,
         first_clob,
         DECODE( end1, 0, 0, end1 + 1 ),
         DECODE( end1, 0, 0, INSTR( first_clob, '|', end1 + 1 ) ),
         another_clob,
         DECODE( end2, 0, 0, end2 + 1 ),
         DECODE( end2, 0, 0, INSTR( another_clob, '|', end2 + 1 ) )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end1 > 0
  OR     end2 > 0
)
SELECT some_id,
       AVG(
         TO_NUMBER(
           CASE
           WHEN start1 = 0 THEN NULL
           WHEN end1 = 0 THEN SUBSTR( first_clob, start1 )
           ELSE SUBSTR( first_clob, start1, end1 - start1 )
           END
         )
       ) AS FIRST_CLOB_MEAN,
       AVG(
         TO_NUMBER(
           CASE
           WHEN start2 = 0 THEN NULL
           WHEN end2 = 0 THEN SUBSTR( another_clob, start2 )
           ELSE SUBSTR( another_clob, start2, end2 - start2 )
           END
         )
       ) AS ANOTHER_CLOB_MEAN
FROM   bounds
GROUP BY some_id
ORDER BY some_id
```

or

```sql
SELECT some_id,
       first_clob_mean,
       another_clob_mean
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT AVG( TO_NUMBER(column_value) ) AS first_clob_mean
         FROM   XMLTABLE( ('"' || REPLACE( t.first_clob, '|', '","' ) || '"') )
       )
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT AVG( TO_NUMBER(column_value) ) AS another_clob_mean
         FROM   XMLTABLE( ('"' || REPLACE( t.another_clob, '|', '","' ) || '"') )
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( some_id, first_clob, another_clob )
SELECT 0, '1.5|3.6|0.3',  '5.5|9.6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '0.2',          '4.0|7.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '3.1|0.7|1.2',  '9.2|8.8|6.3' FROM DUAL;

DECLARE
  v_clob CLOB;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 4000 LOOP
    IF v_clob IS NOT NULL THEN
      v_clob := v_clob || '|';
    END IF;
    v_clob := v_clob || i;
  END LOOP;
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 4, v_clob, NULL );
 END;
 /
```

Both output:

> ```
> SOME_ID |                          FIRST_CLOB_MEAN | ANOTHER_CLOB_MEAN
> ------: | ---------------------------------------: | ----------------:
>       0 |                                      1.8 |              7.55
>       1 |                                       .2 |               5.6
>       2 | 1.66666666666666666666666666666666666667 |               8.1
>       4 |                                   2000.5 |              null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c1b703c33f8d4ebf7954cdd10e0a62bd)*

Answer (score 1):

A query like this one can be used to split the CLOBs by the pipe delimiter, then take the averages. Each CLOB needs to be split in its own sub-query so the count of numbers in the CLOB does not affect the count of numbers in another CLOB in the same row.

```sql
  SELECT c1.some_id, c1.first_clob_mean, c2.another_clob_mean
    FROM (    SELECT some_id,
                     AVG (TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (first_clob,
                                                    '[^|]+',
                                                    1,
                                                    LEVEL)))    AS first_clob_mean
                FROM clobs
          CONNECT BY     LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (first_clob, '\|') + 1
                     AND PRIOR SYS_GUID () IS NOT NULL
                     AND PRIOR some_id = some_id
            GROUP BY some_id) c1,
         (    SELECT some_id,
                     AVG (TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (another_clob,
                                                    '[^|]+',
                                                    1,
                                                    LEVEL)))    AS another_clob_mean
                FROM clobs
          CONNECT BY     LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (another_clob, '\|') + 1
                     AND PRIOR SYS_GUID () IS NOT NULL
                     AND PRIOR some_id = some_id
            GROUP BY some_id) c2
   WHERE c1.some_id = c2.some_id
ORDER BY some_id;
```